# using frameset in Spring 3

Tags: html, spring-mvc, frameset

I am a newbie to Spring 3 , and am learning on my own. I have run into a issue regarding framesets.

In my page , I have included 3 framesets , something like this

`<frameset rows="10">`

`<frame src="/WEB-INF/views/frame1.jsp" name="frame1"scrolling="no">`

`<frameset cols="20%,*">`

`<frame src="/WEB-INF/views/frame2.jsp" name="frame2">`

`<frame src="/WEB-INF/views/frame3.jsp" name="frame3">`

`</frameset>`

`</frameset>`

Now when I run the frameset page it throws a resource not found exception , I do not get why.

Is it that I have to define the mapping for each of the frame*.jsp pages in the Controller. Any examples would be appreciated

Thanks in advance : 
Vivek

Comment: @smp7d , Dave , php-coder
Thank you for the hints, I placed the files outside the WEB-INF and the page worked.
But now the thing that crosses my mind is , is it safe to place these files as publicly accessible. 

Is there a better way to implement framesets or any other equivalent that can be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the browser itself should not be able to access files located under WEB-INF (this is an app-container thing). You'd need to map them to something publicly-accessible; a view, a JSP not under WEB-INF, etc.

Answer (score 1):

All pages inside `WEB-INF` directory not accessed to user, so if this is a simple JSP pages, move it to public folder (and check that it accessable via browser).

Answer (score 1):

A frame source would require an actual mapping or a publicly available file. You will notice that you will get a 404 if you try to hit that resource in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of framesets directly having link to jsp as src, point it to a server side action. Let the action handler (for ex. servlet or spring controller) do a forward to your jsp present inside web-inf.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of not being linked to the jsp page in one frames in the frameset. Note that each frame is a new http request. the flow is  web.xml ---> servletname-servlet.xml --> controller --> view resolver.

put some thing like this in your frameset frame  frame src="frame_b" 
link it with  controller 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/frame_b", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView goFrameb(ModelMap model) {
        return new ModelAndView("frame_b");
        }
view resolver can map to your jsp page like frame_b.jsp
**** jsp is present in web-inf/jsp/*.jsp

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of not being linked to the jsp page in one frames in the frameset.

Note that each frame is a new http request. the flow is web.xml ---> servletname-servlet.xml --> controller --> view resolver.

put some thing like this in your frameset frame
 src of frame has src="frame_b"

link it with controller

@RequestMapping(value = "/frame_b", method = RequestMethod.GET) public ModelAndView goFrameb(ModelMap model) { return new ModelAndView("frame_b"); }

view resolver can map to your jsp page like frame_b.jsp

**** jsp is present in web-inf/jsp/*.jsp